# API Authorised Connection

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to link up Docusign with a third party LetMC.  I have provided our API account number, Docusign login and password details but they came back with the response below.  Docusign customer services were unable to assist.  Can you please tel me what I have to do or provide to connect docusign to our third party LetMC?

> Please can you ask your account manager or support team for your e-sign account to double check your account details to confirm your account is authorized to accept API connections? Basically, the issue lies with the connection. When it attempts to login into your account to actually submit the envelope, your credentials that were given are coming up as invalid. This tells us that either your account isn't authorised to accept the connection to LetMC, or that the details for your account are not correct.
>
> If you can forward this email to them, I am hoping they can can shed some light on the API connection availability. I look forward to your response following their confirmation.

Comment: So did you ask your account manager or support team? Did you double-check your account details?

Comment: We are not your account manager nor support team.

Comment: If you are getting a failed connection, then readers would need to see some sort of logs or failure report in order to be able to help. Presently they'd just be guessing. What details can you provide about this problem to help people help you?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

All DocuSign accounts can accept API input, up to the limits of what the account is normally allowed to do. If you are able to send envelopes through the web console, a properly configured API integration can send envelopes as well.

You'll want to confirm the credentials you provided are in fact accurate (you might consider performing a password reset), and have LetMC contact DocuSign Developer Support in order to identify why they are not able to access your account.